# Using different symbol on vertical line vs horizontal line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, line

I'm working on a map that has an oldtime feel. There are cliffs on the map, some of them are roughly horizontal (running east to west) and some of them roughly vertical (running north to south) that I have indicated using a line. I would like to use a different symbol on the vertical line segments than I use on the horizontal line segments.
I would create another layer, one with horizontal and one with vertical line segments, but this is inconvenient because many of the cliffs curve around. I was hoping there would be a more simple method.

Here's a quick sketch of what I'm trying to accomplish via lines

[image]

Comment: If your dataset has (or you can add) a field with values for horizontal and vertical, then you can use the categorized option in your layer styling.

Comment: In it's current state your goal is a bit unclear could you add a sketch of the desired output and provide more detail on what you have tried ? In the meantime you could try to calculate the bearing of your lines then use rule base or data defined symbology.

Comment: You could do that with a Geometry Generator style and some rules. Please add more details on your data. Is it long lines with multiple curves?

Comment: Yes, it's long lines with multiple curves. Some of the lines have 50+ points that shift from running north-south to east-west in an L or Z shape. Those values that are between 45 to 135 degrees or 225-315degreees  I want to use a symbol that isn't shaded to give the appearance that there is an abrupt cliff. The rest I want to use a symbol that has shading to it. I guess I'm just not sure how to determine the variable for a line's angle as built into QGIS. Is there a way to calculate the slope of a line segment in a line?

Comment: @johns I think your idea would work best but I would rather not manually assign values to a field for that purpose, so I'm wondering if there is a variable built into qgis already that lists the slope or angle of the line segment.

Comment: I'm writing and thinking at the same time here (!), but if there was associated DEM data, then 1) slope and aspect could be generated, 2) and those values transferred to the lines, 3) and then the lines could be styled accordingly by slope and/or aspect.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.